# MVC SelectList is empty in model when Posting back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model:

```
[Display(Name = "Company")]
public int CompanyId { get; set; }

public SelectList Companies { get; set; }
```

Setting Data for view

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Ticket
        {
            Companies = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "0" } }, "Value", "Text")
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

The View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyId, new { @class = "col-md-6 col-md-pull-1 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-1">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.Companies, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Results:

[image: This is the result]

How can i get the SelectList to be posted back to the Controller so i dont have to keep populating it?

Comment: So you want to return the entire list that was passed to view the first time ?

Comment: You don't. You would need to generate a hidden input for each `Value` and `Text` property of each `SelectListItem`, significantly increasing the amount of data you send to the view and then back again. Just get it in the controller POST method again if you need to return the view (which should only be the case if you have `ModelState` errors and using client side validation will reduce the likely hood of that happening anyway)

Comment: And `Companies = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "0" } }, "Value", "Text")` is nonsense. You already have `List<SelectListItem>` (which is what `@Html.DropDownListFor()` requires). Creating another `SelectList` from the existing `SelectList` is just pointless.

Answer (score 1):

`Model.Companies` wont be binded because is not in the Form, the ModelBinder is looking for an input in the Form or a querystring value with the name of the property (in this case Companies) but you don´t have one in the view with that name, on the contrary, you have a field with the name CompanyId, that´s why the property `CompanyId` is binded.

A good way to save your Companies list and get it in the Post action is to use `TempData`, with TempData you can save an item in an action, and it´ll be available to the next action. Is like Session, but just for one Request.